# Adobe Acrobat opens whenever I save a PDF file. Please make it stop!

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

So. I installed Acrobet. I generally like it for dealing with large PDF files. However, since I've installed it, is insists on opening *every time* I download a PDF from Chrome.  I'm sure this is a silly-ass setting somewhere, but I've not found it.

Help?

**Update**

The exact behavior is that I look at the PDF in Chrome, then "Save As" to save it.  At that point the Adobe Acrobat takes over.

Sadly, `chrome://plugins/` is no help.  See screenshot attached:

[image]

Comment: Are you opening the PDF from finder or is chrome pushing the download to open in the app?

Comment: the PDF automatically opens in Acrobat after downloading.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable/remove the Adobe PDF plugin from chrome://plugins/.

As part of the installation of Adobe Acrobat, there is an option to Customise the install and choose whether to install the plugin. It's enabled by default.

Comment: See above, there's no adobe plugin listed.